# "Batch auto-increment" IDs for multiple row insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, auto-increment

I am working in SQL Server 2017, and I have a table of the form:

**tbl_current**

```
COL1   COL2
-----------
 A      1
 B      3
 C     56
```

which I want to periodically insert into the table `tbl_release`.

This table would have an extra ID column, which I'd like to auto-increment with each "batch insertion". For example, let's say I perform the the ingestion of `tbl_current` into `tbl_release`, it would look like this:

**tbl_release**

```
ID   COL1   COL2
----------------
 1    A       1
 1    B       3
 1    C      56
```

Now, let's say I perform another ingestion with the same data, it'd look like:

**tbl_release**

```
ID   COL1   COL2
----------------
 1    A       1
 1    B       3
 1    C      56 
 2    A       1
 2    B       3
 2    C      56
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Is there some SQL Server feature that would allow to achieve this, or do I need to run some sub-queries?

Comment: Would you be inserting the entire contents of tbl_current every time? Like does the table get truncated after?  Or how does it know where to pick up from tbl_current? Or does it just re-insert everything every time?

Comment: Very vague, how are you inserting the data? are you using an INSERT script? are you using an SSIS package, C# application?? We need an idea of your process. Can you provide an example of the script/code that performs the insert?

Comment: SQL Server's IDENTITY columns already batch IDs to handle big insertions. There are also SEQUENCE objects that can be used to get incrementing values. What you posted doesn't look like ID batching at all, rather like using one SEQUENCE value for every row inserted in a certain batch

Comment: @ElementZero yes, I would be inserting the entire contents of tbl_current every time. This table is relatively static, it changes very rarely, some values are just overridden every now and then. Instead, the tbl_release grows constantly, with each insertion of the tbl_current content

Comment: @ChrisCarroll yes I am using an insert script for now. I'm at the very beginning, so using something like INSERT INTO tbl_release (COL1, COL2) SELECT * FROM tbl_current ; I still need to sort out the ID column though, and there may be better ways to insert...

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, it looks like SEQUENCEs may do the job

Comment: @Catazza I would strongly recommend that you use your Id field as an incremental PK style field for each individual row and add a new column called BatchId that will store your info as this is essentially the Id number for each batch, it is not a distinct Id for the table which an Id field should be. for the BatchId field you could look to declare a variable which is the MAX(BatchId) +1 as per answers below. But again I would strongly recommend that it be a new column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd personallly use a sequence for this. Assuming the insert into your ephemeral table is done, it'd looks omething like this:

```
declare @ID int = next value for sequence dbo.mySequence;

insert into tbl_release
   (ID, col1, col2)
select @ID, col1, col2
from tbl_current;
```

Comment: If the OP can't change the client to fetch the sequence number before inserting, he can use an after insert trigger to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `MAX()` function as shown below.

```
Declare @maxId int
set @maxId = (Select isnull(id, 0) from tbl_Current)
set @maxId = @maxId + 1
--Now to insert
insert into tbl_release values (@maxId, <Column1Value>, <Column2Value>)
```

For multiple insert you can try this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_release
SELECT @maxId, col1, col2 FROM tbl_Current
```

If your table's Id column is identity then you can also use the [Scope_Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the max value of Id column.

Comment: `MAX+1` guarantees duplicate values. It's all too easy to get the same ID as a deleted object and end up refering to the wrong record. It's not needed either, since SQL Server has both IDENTITY values and SEQUENCE objects

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, it's also the slowest way to work because it forces a query for each record insertion

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have just give an idea to do that insert option and OP can use identity also. Second everything has their Pros and con. Nothing guarantee 100% perfect even Identity also.

Comment: But this technique is guaranteed to get duplicate values occasionally. There are just way too many issues using max + 1 to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` is really an object.  I would strongly suggest that you give it a full table:

```
create table batches (
    batch_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    batch_start_date datetime,
    . . . 
);
```

Then, your existing table should be structured as:

```
create table releases (
    release_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    batch_id int not null references batches(batch_id),
    col1 char(1),
    col2 int
);
```

That way, your database has referential integrity.